# Add arguments to Phonegap database transaction callback functions

Tags: javascript, cordova

Looking at this Phonegap example implementation:

```
//Create database if not exist
var transaction = function (tx) {

tx.executeSql(query);


};

//error callback if any errors occured during a transaction
var errorCB = function (the_error) {

   console.log(the_error);
}

//success callback when database transaction successful
var successCB = function () {

   console.log("transaction success");
}


//initialise
function init() {

db = window.openDatabase("db", "1.0", "Database", 2000000);
db.transaction(transaction, errorCB, successCB);

};
```

How can I add an extra argument to the callback functions?

I would like to have the same callbacks per each transaction and pass the transaction id/name so to identify it without having to write a different callback each time

All the examples I have seen are for a single transaction. The `error` object passed to the errorCB does not contain the transaction identifier or similar.
If I have multiple `db.transaction` calls (each one with one or more tx.executeSql) will I have to write different callbacks all the time?

I am looking for something like:
`db.transaction(transaction, errorCB(tx_name), successCB(tx_name));`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.transaction(transaction, 
    function(tx){errorCB(tx, tx_name);}, 
    function(tx){successCB(tx, tx_name);}
);

function errorCB(tx, tx_name) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
}

function successCB(tx, tx_name) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```